# Lattice which is not bounded lattice

Tags: discrete-mathematics, lattice-orders

I want to find an example of a lattice which is not a bounded lattice . Diagrams would be good with an explanation .

Comment: $(\mathbb Z,\le)$

Comment: Can u explain ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is the set of all integers, and $\le$ is the usual ordering: $$\dots\lt-3\lt-2\lt-1\lt0\lt1\lt2\lt3\lt\dots$$

Comment: Is it because of fact set of all integers does not have a greatest or least element which tends to infinty ?

Comment: The set $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the usual $\leq$ order is another example.  It is not bounded below (above) because there is no element in $(0,1)$ that is less (greater) than every other element.

Comment: From @Greg: Just to add to earlier comments: a lattice can be viewed either as an algebraic structure (wikipedia) or as a partially ordered set (,≤) such that every cardinality-2 subset {,}⊂ has a supremum ∨ and infimum ∧. If you take the latter view, then, by definition, your lattice is bounded if and only if it contains a "top element" ⊤ and "bottom element" ⊥ such that ⊥≤≤⊤ for all ∈.

Comment: From @Greg: The partially ordered set (ℤ,≤) is an order lattice because every pair of integers , has a supremum ∨=max{,} and infimum ∧=min{,}. However, no one integer is greater or equal to every other integer. Similarly no integer is less than or equal to every other integer. Therefore the lattice (ℤ,≤) does not have top or bottom elements. Therefore it is not bounded.

Comment: My obvious choice would  be the empty lattice $(\emptyset,\le).$

Answer (score 4):

All finite lattices are bounded. $(\Bbb N,|)$ is an example of an unbounded lattice. Or you can add the Hasse diagram of $\Bbb Z$ above the maximum element of  the Hasse diagram of any bounded lattice to get an unbounded lattice.

Answer (score -2):

The given poset is a lattice because any given pair of elements do have a lowest upper bound (LUB), but it tends to positive infinite for very large integers. By a similar reasoning, the GLB tends to negative infinite for very large negative integers. Therefore, LUB and GLB, even though they exist, are not bounded. Thus, the given poset is an unbounded lattice. This concept would be clearer if you were to draw the same conclusions from the Hasse diagram.